# VHDL Ripple Counter (using 3 D-type FF)

Tags: vhdl, counter

I cannot find a single website showing the VHDL code for a basic Ripple Counter (made of 3 D-type Flip Flops). Could you post the code below or point to resources to find the answer. I presume it is only a few lines long...

Comment: You won't find it on websites, you'll probably have to write your own.

Comment: It is such a common component I am guessing there is a standard way of writing it...

Comment: None are D-type FF implementations

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can easily define it as a bank of D flip-flips, connecting to each input D its output Q inverted. The clock connections are also the previous flip-flop outputs unless the first on the bank, which gets the general clock.

Hope this helps... You might want to try it yourself :)